# python nested function's accessibility to outer variable

Tags: python

I wonder why reference variable(dict, list) is accessible from nested function while simple object is not.

```
In [1]: a = 1

In [2]: b = [1]

In [3]: c = {"c" : 1}

In [4]:

In [4]: def f():
   ...:         a = 2
   ...:         b[0] = 2
   ...:         c["c"] = 2
   ...:

In [5]: f()

In [6]:

In [6]: print a
1

In [7]: print b
[2]

In [8]: print c
{'c': 2}
```

Comment: Because integer is immutable while lists and dictionaries are mutable read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python.

Answer (score 1):

Integer is immutable, that means when python execute

```
a=2 inside f()
```

It create a new local object. While list and dictionary is mutable, so it can be modified in place.

```
>>> a = 0
>>> id(a)
31367908
>>> ls = [1,2]
>>> id(ls)
50082760
>>> def f():
    a = 2
    print id(a)
    ls[0] = 5
    print id(ls)


>>> f()
31367884
50082760
```

Answer (score 0):

With statement `a = 2` you are creating new **local variable** with value `2`. However when you modify `b[0]` or `c['c']` you are mutating **global variable**. If  you have to deal with mutable types in function (work with them as with local variables) you have to initialize appropriate variable before mutating it:

```
def f():
  c = {}
  b = []
  c['c'] = 2
  b.append(1)
```

See [Variables and scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Variables_and_Scope.html) chapter with great description of how scope works in python and get more info about mutable and immutable types.